# After changing to @font-face, lists are spaced out?

Tags: css, font-face

I have a font installed on my pc, but after using a font-face converter and changing the css suitably, the lines in my ul are more spaced out, the font-size hasn't changed, but the spacing between them has. What CSS do I need to use to revert this? Example: http://www.givetoagiver.co.cc/about.php
If you need any more information, then please ask, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `letter-spacing` (http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_letter-spacing.asp)
- `line-height` (http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_dim_line-height.asp)

The above two take care of all the distanced between lines and individual characters.

Still, if the font works OK when it's installed locally, there's a chance the conversion process introduced the problem. What tool have you used for the conversion? Have you tried [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface)'s converter? I've never had issues with it.

PS. The link you provided does not seem to work for me.

[EDIT]

@Yi Jiang suggested these links as an alternative to the ones provided by me:

- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/letter-spacing
- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/line-height

Comment: You can use `<link_url>` to force those links into anchors, actually - that was really what the edit was about

Answer (score 0):

Each font can have its own spacing. Web fonts usually uses both the same spacing, so we use them without any issue. with custom fonts, sometimes we've got to change the line-height accordingly:

```
font: 44px/1.2em Sohoma;
```

1.2em is the line-height.

Comment: 1.2em line height looks right, but it leaves the content of the li off-centre, I ended up doing this: line-height:70%; padding-top:26px;